# Angular2 Custom Events

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to find out how to handle custom DOM events emitted by something outside of Angular, for example the following:

```
document.querySelector('my-custom-element').dispatchEvent(new Event('my.customEvent'));
```

So far I have tried to register a new EventManagerPlugin that supports everything starting with 'my.' but if I print out all events that come by all 'normal' event like 'click' and 'submit' are printed out; but none of my custom events.

html:

```
<my-custom-element (my.customEvent)="handleCustomEvent($event)"></my-custom-element>
```

ts:

```
supports(eventName: string):boolean {
    var ret = false;
    if (eventName.indexOf('my.') === 0) {
        ret = true;
    }
    console.log('supports event?', eventName, ret);
    return ret;
}
```

The console.log line only prints native events and ng*events but not my custom event :(

**EDIT Fixed solution**
I've moved the (my.customEvent) inside the component annd the log showed the custom event.
Binding an external event to the angular2 internal event while seperating the 2 is fixed by using a custom eventHandler in the EventManagerPlugin
Relevate code

```
addEventListener(element: HTMLElement, eventName: string, handler: Function): Function {
    let zone = this.manager.getZone();

    // Entering back into angular to trigger changeDetection
    var outsideHandler = (event: any) => {
        zone.run(() => handler(event));
    };

    // Executed outside of angular so that change detection is not constantly triggered.
    var addAndRemoveHostListenersForOutsideEvents = () => {
        this.manager.addEventListener(element, 'external.' + eventName, outsideHandler);
    }
    return this.manager.getZone().runOutsideAngular(addAndRemoveHostListenersForOutsideEvents);
}
```

Trigger the event via DOM:

```
document.querySelector('my-custom-element').dispatchEvent(new Event('external.my.customEvent'));
```

Now you can trigger an event from the DOM which is pushed into angular2 world and can the code is handled from within the component.

Comment: Can you provide some plunker that reproduces your problem? Here is sample https://plnkr.co/edit/qvtmFfR9TEp0dxaDsaOY?p=preview See console

Comment: @yurzui: thank you for the plunker; only thing I had to do to make the 'support' part work was to move the events lower into the HTML.

The eventlistener does not listen to the events fired by the dispatchEvent though. Still puzzeling on how to write it so it listens outside of angular2 but handles from within angular2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend the `DomEventsPlugin`, for example:

```
import {DomEventsPlugin} from 'angular2/platform/common_dom';
// Have to pull DOM from src because platform/common_dom returns DOM as null.
// I believe its a TS bug.
import {DOM} from 'angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {noop} from 'angular2/src/facade/lang';

@Injectable()
export class DOMOutsideEventPlugin extends DomEventsPlugin {
  eventMap: Object = {
    "clickOutside": "click",
    "mousedownOutside": "mousedown",
    "mouseupOutside": "mouseup",
    "mousemoveOutside": "mousemove"
  }
  supports(eventName: string): boolean {
    return this.eventMap.hasOwnProperty(eventName);
  }

  addEventListener(element: HTMLElement, eventName: string, handler: Function): Function {
    var zone = this.manager.getZone();
    var documentEvent = this.eventMap[eventName];

    // Entering back into angular to trigger changeDetection 
    var outsideHandler = (event) => {
        zone.run(() => handler(event))
    };

    // Executed outside of angular so that change detection is not constantly triggered.
    var addAndRemoveHostListenersForOutsideEvents = () => {
      DOM.onAndCancel(DOM.getGlobalEventTarget('document'), documentEvent,
        (event) => {
          let current = event.target;
          // if the element/event is propagating from the element its bound to, don't handle it.
          if (current.parentNode && current !== element) {
              outsideHandler(event);
        }
      });
    }
    return this.manager.getZone().runOutsideAngular(addAndRemoveHostListenersForOutsideEvents);
  }

  addGlobalEventListener(target: string, eventName: string, handler: Function): Function {
    var element = DOM.getGlobalEventTarget(target);
    var zone = this.manager.getZone();
    var outsideHandler = (event) => zone.run(() => handler(event));

    if ((target === "document") || (target === "window" )) {
      return noop;
    }
    return this.manager.getZone().runOutsideAngular(
        () => DOM.onAndCancel(element, eventName, outsideHandler)
    );
  }
}
```

source: https://medium.com/@TheLarkInn/creating-custom-dom-events-in-angular2-f326d348dc8b#.so0jvssnz

Comment: This code is really old but I've ported it over to RC4; unfortunately the supports method still only prints native and angular-specific events; which works in that case but not mine; where I want to use real custom events.